# What happens when a string literal passed as const string& to a function?

Tags: c++, string

Here is an example from the *C++ Primer*:
A function `count()` declared as:

```
int count(const string & a, char b);
```

and called:

```
count("abcde", 'a')
```

It works. Here `"abcde"` is a string literal and passed to `count()` as `const string &`.

But at the same time this code

```
string & s="abcde";
```

was wrong simply because we cannot assign a `string` literal to a `string &`.

So what happened when `"abcde"` was passed to `count()`? Is there something like a temporary string be initialized by `"abcde"` and then passed to `count()`?

Comment: Your second example doesn't work because you omitted the `const`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there something like a temporary string be initialized by `"abcde"` and then passed to `count()`?

Yes, that's exactly what happens there.

A temporary instance of `std::string` is constructed using the [implicit constructor (5)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string)

```
 basic_string( const CharT* s,
               const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );
```

and passed as rvalue reference to the function.

---

As for your second sample this would work with a `const` reference as well:

```
const std::string& s = "abcde";
```

<sub>[see demo](http://ideone.com/XWSFcf)</sub>

The point is a lvalue reference can't be initialized from a rvalue.

Comment: can we consider it as compiler smartness or its dumbness?

Comment: @Nishant It's just how implicit constructors work. A simple non const reference can't be initialized from a rvalue, that's all.

Comment: can i know address of temporary string created?

Comment: @nishant yes you can

Comment: @Yakk Questionable though what to do with that address. I didn't respond so far, because I didn't get what that comment question is about actually.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Sure, there are few good reasons to use the address.  But you can get the address of a temporary through a number of ways.